# What is the better way to resize UITableView Cells components

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a big problem, I' trying to resize a cell and its two views inside the cell, I did it but it's showed slow when the `UITableView` is showed, I suppose this is happening because all the things that the cell should do before show up.

This is a resume that what I am doing to resize the cell and its content:

1. Resize the cell using `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
2. Resize a custom view inside the cell `- (void)sizeForContent:(UICustomView*)contentView andCommentView:(UIOtherCustomView*)commentView forMessage:(MessageObject*)message`
3. And at the end I resize a label inside the first `UIView`

(I'm doing the last to steps in 
`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`)

It is generated that it should, but the table is running to slow!.

This is a example that what I'm generating inside each cell (the second view is showed only if there is information to show there, the first one is always showed)

```
--------------------
|                  |
|   First UIView   |
|   | UILabel |    |
--------------------
    |  Second UIView |
    |                |
    |----------------|
```

What is the better way to resize all the components inside the cell? Is there a way to use autolayout for that?

Comment: Please show the code so we can understand what exactly it is that you are doing

Comment: ok let me put some code here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `UICollectionView` instead, as it is designed to be more flexible in terms of layout and cell size. The basic functionality is quite similar to `UITableView`.

See Apples Documentation on Collection Views: [About UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Using UICollectionView can I simulate a UITableView?. What is the difference when UICollectionView generate each cell?

Comment: By defining the size of each cell to anything close to the width of the `UICollectionView`, you can make it look like a `UITableView` to the user. Alternatively you may implement an entirely custom layout. While it may be more work to implement a `UICollectionView`, there are fewer constraints in terms of layout, cell alignment and especially animation. The data source on the other hand is implemented similar to a tableView. So, if you want to display cells of different sizes you should definitely look at Apples doc on that topic.